# user authentication with php class. is this right?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, class, error-handling

This is my first attempt to create a class.

I created a User class which does login, registration and logout.

It seems it's working but I'm sure I've done something wrong. For example when I only use login() method why do I have to give all variables that I created in ___construct. for login I only need username and password.

I display errors with $_ERROR variable in my template system. How do I display errors in class. I used throw new ExampleException

Could anyone review my class and tell me the mistakes I made please? I just want to learn how to use class...

this is my class

```
<?php
class User
{

var $Username = '';
var $Email = '';
var $Password = '';
var $Salt = '';

protected $_username;
protected $_email;
protected $_password;
protected $_salt;

protected $_db;
protected $_user;

public function __construct(PDO $db, $Username, $Email, $Password, $Salt)
{
    $this->_db = $db;
    $this->_username = $Username;
    $this->_email = $Email;
    $this->_password = $Password;
    $this->_salt = $Salt;

}

private function saltString($Password) // Creates random string for password
{
    $Characters = 'PEcN0';
    $string = md5( $Password . $Characters );

    return $string;
}

public function login() // checks if CheckCredentials is true. if it's true it creates sessions
{
    $user = $this->_CheckCredentials();
    if($user){
        $this->_user = $user;
        $_SESSION['UserID'] = $user['UserID'];
        $_SESSION['Username'] = $user['Username'];
        $_SESSION['Level'] = $user['Level'];
        $_SESSION['Reputation'] = $user['Reputation'];
        return $user['UserID'];
    }
    return false;
}

public function register() // checks if addUser is true.
{
    $user = $this->_addUser();
    if($user){
        $this->createSession($user);    
    }
    return false;
}

public function _CheckCredentials() // checks password and username for login method
{
    $sql = $this->_db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '" . $this->_username . "'");

    if($sql->rowCount() > 0){
        $user = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $pass = $this->saltString($this->_password);
        if($pass == $user['Password']){
            $sql = $this->_db->query( "UPDATE users SET LastLogin = NOW() WHERE UserID = '" . $user['UserID'] . "'" );
            return $user;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function _addUser() // add user into database
{
    $sql = $this->_db->query( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '" . $this->_username . "' OR Email = '" . $this->_email . "'" );
    if($sql->rowCount()){
        $user = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($user['Username'] == $this->_username){
            throw new ExampleException("This username was taken.");
        }else{
            throw new ExampleException("This e-mail address is being used.");
        }
    }else{
        $intert = $sql->query( "INSERT INTO users ( UserID, OauthUid, OauthProvider, Username, Password, Email, CookieKey, Level, Registered, LastLogin, Reputation, Contents )
        VALUES ( NULL, '". $UserID ."', '". $Provider ."', '" . $Username . "', '" . $Password . "', '" . $Email . "', '" . generateKey( 5 ) . "', '1', NOW(), NOW(), '0', '0')" );

        $UserID = $sql->lastInsertId();

        if($instert){
            $_SESSION['UserID'] = $UserID;
            $_SESSION['Username'] = $Username;
            $_SESSION['Level'] = '1';
        }
    }
    return false;

}

public function getUser()
{
    return $this->_username;
}

}
?>
```

and this is how I use it...

```
<?php

if ( isset( $_POST['Username'] ) )
{
$Username =  trim( $_POST['Username'] );
$Password =  trim( $_POST['Password'] );

if ( !preg_match( '/^[a-z0-9_]+$/i', $Username ) )
    $_ERROR = 'bad username!';
else
{
    $UserClass = new User($dbc, $Username, $Email, $Password, $Salt);

    if($userid = $UserClass->login())
    {
        if ( isset( $_POST['Remember'] ) )
        {
            setcookie( 'UserID', $data['UserID'], time() + 31536000, '/', SITE );
            setcookie( 'PassHash', md5( $data['Password'] .     $data['CookieKey'] ), time() + 31536000, '/', SITE );
        }

        header( "Location: " . ( $_POST['Redirect'] != '' ? base64_decode(     $_POST['Redirect'] ): '/index.php' ) );
        die();
    }
    else
        $_ERROR = "Check your username or password!";
        $_INFO .= $_SESSION['UserID'];

}
}else{

$Reff = '';
if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) )
$Reff = base64_encode( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );

$_INFO .= $_SESSION['UserID'];
$_PAGE .= t_LoginForm( $Reff );


}

?>
```

Comment: why people downvotes this? I haven done anything wrong. don't downvote people just because you don't like the coding or question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using PDO which is always a plus but the problem is that you are not binding your parameters. The biggest plus to PDO is actually binding parameters. In your example :

```
$sql->bindParam(':userid',$UserID);
$sql->bindParam(':provider',$Provider);
```

and so on...............

Second part that is scaring me and should scare you if you read up on password security is this that you are using md5 for your passwords with just a random key string called $characters that you just concatenate? That sir... is... just... stupid (sorry for be blunt but this in fact is a big issue and could cause your clients / user massive troubles WHICH IS VERY SERIOUS).

Here try this [Bcrypt Library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). It is 2013 YOU SHOULD NOT BE USING md5 even with a salt and even with the method that you are doing so :

```
 $Characters = 'PEcN0';
    $string = md5( $Password . $Characters );

    return $string;
```

Trust me stay away from building your own "encryption/hashing" methods and use a community trusted method.

Also back to the PDO part, don't forget to add this to your attributes :

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
```

I hope you learn something from this post. You should not be using PDO without bindParam, and you should not be using MD5 at all with or without a salt. Bcrypt Bcrypt Bcrypt Bcrypt Bcrypt.

Comment: Thank you i have already added the attributes in my config file. What do you mean by community trusted method. what people usually do?

Comment: Yes that is correct. If you go to the library link you will see how many people use it. Just by googling bcrypt php you will see that using bcrypt should be seen as more of a standard rather then a best practice. Bcrypt password security is far far more secure then me5 will ever be.

Comment: Also realise as well when I say community trusted I also refer to the people who don't roll their own password protection schemes. And use bcrypt libraries. There are more then just the one I linked to. I just use that Inge for forward compatibility

Comment: thank you very much. because this question downvoted i'm not able to ask anymore question.

Comment: No problem follow those guidelines I posted plus validation+filtering and escape all data that is user imputed. Good luck.